# STL Vector push_back()

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I've found the following example. I haven't used STL before and I want to understand what is it doing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#define maxn 100010

int N, M, L, Start;
vector <int> A[maxn];

int main()
{
    int i, x, y;
    scanf("%d %d %d ", &N, &M, &Start);

    for (i = 1; i <= M; i++) 
    {
        scanf("%d %d ", &x, &y);
        A[x].push_back(y);
    }

return 0;
}
```

I'm talking about *A[x].push_back(y);*. From what I see in the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) it adds a new element at the end of the vector and increases the vectors size by one. Since I am reading pair of numbers (x,y) does that mean that after every **x** read there will be a **y**? So in the end my vector it will be something like [x][y][x'][y'][x''][y'']?

Comment: Off topic, the practice is to declare variables at the point of usage, not *exactly* one scope before.

Comment: `vector <int> A[maxn];` is an array (of vectors).

Comment: What if `x >= 100010`?  It is an out-of-bounds access in that loop.

Comment: @Danh: If you think reading a good book would be helpful, leaving a comment linking to that list is fine, but it's not a good duplicate target.

Answer (score 0):

> Since I am reading pair of numbers (x,y) does that mean that after every x read there will be a y?

No it doesn't. The user could input a non-integer such as "fubar" and cause scanf to fail. There is no test for scanf failing, so it is possible that the program will accept an x without a y.

`scanf` returns the number of inputs successfully read, so

```
if (scanf("%d %d ", &x, &y) == 2)
{
    A[x].push_back(y);
}
else
{
    // Inform user of error
}
```

will catch simple errors.

> So in the end my vector it will be something like [x][y][x'][y'][x''][y'']

`y` is `push_back`ed, not used as an index, so rather than

```
[x][y][x'][y'][x''][y'']
```

`A` will look more like

```
[x][0] == y
[x'][0] == y'
[x''][0] == y''
```

with any `A[i]` where no x,y pair was provided being an empty `vector`. To keep the example simple, consider input of 3 3, 3 3, 5 7

```
[0][0] == out of range access. undefined behaviour
[1][0] == out of range access. undefined behaviour
[2][0] == out of range access. undefined behaviour
[3][0] == 3
[3][1] == 3
[3][2] == out of range access. undefined behaviour
[4][0] == out of range access. undefined behaviour
[5][0] == 7
[5][1] == out of range access. undefined behaviour
[6][0] == out of range access. undefined behaviour
[7][0] == out of range access. undefined behaviour
...
[10010][0] == out of range access. undefined behaviour
```

To get

```
[x][y][x'][y'][x''][y'']
```

I suspect you need to implement a sparse array data structure, but i'm not certain. A poor man's solution would be to use a `std::map` of `std::map`s:

```
std::map<int,std::map<int,UNKNOWN_DATATYPE> A;
```